# AngularJS object field not updating from child directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

I have a parent controller `A`, who's scope contains an object representing its state. So I can access `state.status` from `A`'s scope to update its status.

I have a child directive, `B`, who has a binding to a field in `A`'s status object. This allows me to update `A`'s state from `B`.

Here's the simplified code for my controller `A`:

```
angular.module("myApp").controller('A', function($scope){

    $scope.state = {
        "status": "All"
    };


    function doSomething() {
        console.log(state.status);
    }

});
```

And for the directive `B`:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('B', function () {

    return {
        templateUrl: 'B.html',
        scope: {
            selectedStatus: '=status',
            onChange: '=onChange'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.setStatus = function(status) {
                scope.selectedStatus = status;
                scope.onChange();
            };
        }
    }

});
```

In the DOM:

```
<B status="state.status" on-change="doSomething" />
```

When I call `setStatus()` from within my directive `B`, I expect the changes I've made to the object to be propagated by the time `doSomething()` is called. However, the `console.log()` output is of the old value, not what I've just updated it to. The change is made, just not fast enough.

I've tried to call `$scope.$apply()` however it complains that it's within a `$scope.$apply()` call already. :(

What's the best way to deal with this?

Comment: _selectedStatus_ is reference to _status_ so when you assign it, you simple chenge reference

Comment: Why don't you pass new status directly to `scope.onChange()` callback.

Comment: @Grundy it's a binding, so when I change `selectedStatus` it changes `state.status`, just with a delay. That's my issue

Comment: @jad-panda There are other fields being updated in the same way, so it would turn into a mess quite quickly. Trying to nail the design

Comment: instead of using callback, You can use `$watch` in A function. watch will only trigger when you have updated data in A from any changes done in Child B.

Comment: @jad-panda However, if my update mutates the state again, will I not be looking at an infinite chain of update state > handle update > update state > handle update > ...?

Comment: @karmat take a look at `$emit` if it could help by anyway

Comment: @karmat can you provide sample `'B.html'`?

Answer (score 1):

Methinks you are a bit confused about how this works.

When you do something like `status="state.status"` and change status inside a directive, changes will be applied only after executing the digest cycle, but in your case you try to output `state.status` before finishing the digest, so it doesn't use the synchronized value.

There are a few ways to solve this:

1. call `scope.onChange` inside `$timeout`
2. pass full object `state` instead `state.status`
3. use `scope.$parent` for access to parent scope where you define `state` object

```js
angular.module("myApp", []).directive('bb', function($timeout) {
  return {
    template: '<div><div ng-click="setStatus1(\'status1\')">1. Selected status: {{selectedStatus}}</div><div ng-click="setStatus2(\'status2\')">2. Selected status: {{selectedStatus}}</div><div ng-click="setStatus3(\'status3\')">3. Selected status: {{selectedStatus}}</div></div>',
    scope: {
      selectedStatus: '=status',
      onChange: '=onChange',
      state: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.setStatus1 = function(status) {
        console.log('setstatus1');
        scope.selectedStatus = status;
        $timeout(function() {
          scope.onChange();
        });
      };
      scope.setStatus2 = function(status) {
        console.log('setstatus2');
        scope.selectedStatus = status;
        scope.state.status = status;
        scope.onChange();
      };
      scope.setStatus3 = function(status) {
        console.log('setstatus3');
        scope.selectedStatus = status;
        scope.$parent.state.status = status;
        scope.onChange();
      };
    }
  }

}).controller('A', function($scope) {

  $scope.state = {
    "status": "All"
  };
  $scope.doSomething = doSomething;

  function doSomething() {
    console.log('doSomething: ', $scope.state.status);
  }

});
```

```html
<script data-require="angular.js@1.4.0-rc.1" data-semver="1.4.0-rc.1" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.8/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="A">
  <bb status="state.status" state="state" on-change="doSomething"></bb>
  {{state}}
</div>
```

Comment: The `$timeout` method didn't work in my code, however I think I had the wrong idea anyway. Seems silly to rely on angular to pass values around when you can just used a shared object reference to modify the same fields. Got this working using #2 you listed - thanks!

Comment: @karmat, without your code we can only guess why `$timeout` not work in your case :-)

Comment: @karmat as you can see - in snippet code from your OP, and `$timeout` work fine, so some difference with code and snippet

Answer (score 0):

In parent directive instead of passing callback, you can use `$watch`.

```
angular.module("myApp").controller('A', function($scope){

    $scope.state = {
        "status": "All"
    };

    $scope.$watch('state', function(newVal, oldVal){
       if(oldVal === newVal) return;

       // Do something using newVal
    }, true);

});
```

Comment: Causes an infinite chain of watch calls if I try to mutate the state from inside the `$watch` callback. You also have the parameters backwards, updating now.

Comment: did you try this `$scope.$watch('state.status', function(new){ // code } );`, only checking in `A` for `state.status` and don't update `state.status` inside `A`

Comment: Then I'll have to do that for all the different fields of my state.. still no good.

Comment: create a jsfiddle and share that code. so i can take a look that. it will give me more insight about the problem

Comment: I provided the necessary code already; just duplicate the directive `B` for different fields and you can see it starts to get out of hand. :)

Comment: try executing callback in `$timeout`, code-  `$timeout(function(){ scope.onChange();  });`

Comment: This didn't work for me, although it was an advised solution elsewhere too